# simple UI menu and canvas for DK2

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

I am using `Unity 5.1.2p3` with `DK2 SDK 0.6.0.1` and I understand from [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-1-vr-getting-started.332316/) post that `Screen Space - Overlay` is not supported in Unity VR. It is recommended to use `Screen Space - Camera` (which in my case does not work) or `World Space` (which I am using now) but I need someone to help me understand how I get simple menu with buttons and toggles to show as a still image and how I can make selections and button presses with my mouse cursor.

I have created a menu for my app, with 4 toggles and 1 button. When I check the `Virtual Reality Supported` option with the Oculus being in `Direct Mode` and Canvas being in `World Space`, I can see it in VR, but I cannot see/find my mouse cursor to tick one of the toggles.

When I take off the headset, on my monitor's `Game View` tab, I can see and even use the mouse and select a toggle. Obviously, I have to keep the headset steady, so in my Game View, things do not shake!

Another thing I notice is that the VR camera is the same as the `Main Camera` in the Unity Hierarchy, but when I take off the headset and move it around, the position of the camera does not change, only looking up and down and around is reflected.

How do I simply do a static menu like a 2D surface that does not move in VR and a user can use button presses and muse clicks with the headset on? What settings are required for this way of doing UI and canvas stuff? There are 2 attachments, showing my current settings...

[image: canvas settings]

[image: player settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you specifically wanting to use the mouse? If you look through a blog entry I wrote below, it will show you how to use Gaze looking to trigger menu buttons:

http://talesfromtherift.com/vr-gaze-input/

You can achieve this by some code I list there that raycasts from the center of the screen and if it hits any UI, it will trigger the correct events and make it clickable by button (or by time).